# Using the same actionListener to open individual GUI's for each button on a grid

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jinternalframe

I have a loop that makes a 3x3 grid of buttons. I'm trying to make it so when the button is pressed, a window opens for the user to add data about the button. The window opens up and everything works for the first time. Once I save this window and click a new button, there is a white square (probably the panel) covering everything. If I make the window bigger I can see the text fields behind it but the white square stays at the same size (size of non expanded window). After ex;anding the window I cab se that the data I added for the last button is still present in the 'new' window, letting me know that I am probably opening the same window and new ones aren't being created. Is there a way to create a totally new window each time?

Here is the loop to create the buttons

```
    for (int i = 0; i < addButtons3.length; i++) {
       addButtons3[i] = new JButton("     Add Bed     "); // make text big
       addButtons3[i].addActionListener(new RoomListener());
       addButtons3[i].setActionCommand("" + i);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
       room3Panel.add(addButtons3[i]);
    }
```

here is the actionListener for each button

```
class  RoomListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    AbstractButton btn = (AbstractButton) event.getSource();
    source = event.getActionCommand();
    System.out.println(source);
    x = Integer.parseInt(source);
    y = Integer.parseInt(roomSource);
    btn.setText("Adding bed..");    

    intFrame8.setMaximizable(true); //Add maximize
    intFrame8.setIconifiable(true); //Make it configurable
    intFrame8.setResizable(true); //Make it resizable
    intFrame8.setClosable(true); //How will it react on close?
    intFrame8.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); //Like this   
    intFrame8.setSize(320,240);
    desktopPane.add(intFrame8);

    JPanel addRoomPanel = new JPanel();
    addRoomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1,5,5)); //row/col/rspace/cspace
    addRoomPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    intFrame8.getContentPane().add(addRoomPanel);   
    intFrame8.toFront();

    //Name text field
    nameLabel.setText("Name: ");
    name.addActionListener(new nameListener());
    addRoomPanel.add(nameLabel);
    addRoomPanel.add(name);

    //DoB text field
    dobLabel.setText("Date of Birth: ");
    dob.addActionListener(new dobListener());
    addRoomPanel.add(dobLabel);
    addRoomPanel.add(dob);

    //Passport Number text field
    passNum.addActionListener(new passNumListener());
    addRoomPanel.add(passNumLabel);
    addRoomPanel.add(passNum);

    //Start Date text field
    startDate.addActionListener(new startDateListener());
    addRoomPanel.add(startDateLabel);
    addRoomPanel.add(startDate);

    //End Date text field
    endDate.addActionListener(new endDateListener());
    addRoomPanel.add(endDateLabel);
    addRoomPanel.add(endDate);

    //Comments section text field
    comments.addActionListener(new commentsListener());
    addRoomPanel.add(commentsLabel);
    addRoomPanel.add(comments);

    addBedSave.addActionListener(new bedSaveListener());
    addRoomPanel.add(addBedSave);

    intFrame8.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the actionListener for the 'save' button that closes the window

```
class bedSaveListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(nameTemp);
        nameList[x][y] = nameTemp;
        dobList[x][y] = dobTemp;
        startDateList[x][y] = startDateTemp;
        endDateList[x][y] = endDateTemp;
        passNumList[x][y] = passNumTemp;
        commentsList[x][y] = commentsTemp;
        intFrame8.dispose();

        switch(y){
        case 0:
            intFrame4.toFront();
            addButtons1[x].setText(nameTemp);
            break;
        case 1:
            intFrame5.toFront();
            addButtons2[x].setText(nameTemp);
            break;
        case 2:
            intFrame6.toFront();
            addButtons3[x].setText(nameTemp);
            break;
        case 3:
            intFrame7.toFront();
            addButtons4[x].setText(nameTemp);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: edit: I'm kinda seeing that I need to open a window instead create a frame. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for opening something like an optionPane with the same functionality as the frame I have made? thanks in advance

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would but the actual code I have is huge and all the variables are liked in very specific ways (lots of texted internal frames).

Comment: As I said, it's not a code dump but demonstration of your work flow which duplicates your issue, without this, it's all just guess work

Comment: Where's the part that creates a new window?

Comment: @immibis Ive made the actionListener create the window in the hope that it will make unique windows for each button (each button has a new version of the actionListener class)

Comment: @ChrisCollins I don't see anything that creates a new window, just some code that adds a bunch of things to a window that already exists, then makes it visible.

Comment: Sorry for the mess of a question guys, the frame itself was defined at the top of the code, outside of the constructor. The actionListener was adding things to the frame each time it was called and that was the problem. I have now added everything to the frame at the top of my code (outside of the constructor) and the actionListener simply makes the window visible and clears the textFields. My problem was that the actionListener was adding the textFields to the window each time I clicked a button, causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation: Use `if(e.getSource == some_JButton){//code}` for your ActionListeners.